# Call function on a JFrame from a JPanel class

Tags: java, swing, nullpointerexception

I have a login `JPanel` which was programmatically added inside the `JFrame`. The problem is I want to call a function on a `JFrame` from the login `JPanel` class using a button.

Here, I've declared the `MainFrame` as `mainFrame` in the `PartLogin` `JPanel` class:

```
public class PartLogin extends JPanel {

    MainFrame mainFrame;
```

Then, I've created a public function from the `JFrame`, then called it from `PartLogin` through a button click

```
mainFrame.changeLabel();
```

I've got an `NullPointerException` pointing inside the buttonclick code.

```
mainFrame.changeLabel();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `NullPointerException` normally says that an object that is needed to be not null is null. Here, this is probably `mainFrame`. Java is not C++, so the statement is equal to:

```
MainFrame mainFrame = null;
```

You should change this so that `mainFrame` is not null. There are two ways:

1. assign value in declaration:

   ```
   MainFrame mainFrame = new MainFrame();
   ```
2. assign value in constructor:

   ```
   private MainFrame mainFrame; // don't must be private

   public PartLogin ()
   {
       super(); // call ctor of superclass
       mainFrame = new MainFrame();
       // ...
   }
   ```

Comment: wow that worked! Am I too obvious that I came from C++? Btw, you've saved me :D

Comment: @PrincetonMielJurilla If the answer worked then please mark the answer as accepted. And C++ automatically assigns non-pointer variables, this is something I often mix up ;)